# javascript working in firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This code:

```
$('#ad img').each(function(){
    if($(this).width() > 125){
        $(this).height('auto');
        $(this).width(125);
    }
});
```

is working properly on Firefox but not Chrome. The `img` tags inside of `#ad` are constricted by `height`, but if this makes them too wide I need to restrain the width. Is there a better way to do this that would work on all browsers?

The html for the image is as follows:

```
<img src='http://easyuniv.com/img/ads/".$ad['img']."' height='40px'>
```

Comment: [Check this, working in chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/tPCp5/4/).

Comment: this is becoz in chrome your image is loaded after the your code is executed causing you error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what is biting you is the variability in image load.  If the image itself hasn't loaded by the time your code runs, it will have width of 0.  You might want to try using a load handler as well as running your existing code to ensure that the images are sized properly.  Note: you'll need to use your existing code to handle the case where the image is loaded before the load handler is added.

```
$(function() {
    $('#ad img').on('load', function() {
          resize(this);
    }).each( function() {
          resize(this);
    });

    function resize(image) {
       var $image = $(image);
       if ($image.width() > 125) {
           $image.css( { height: 'auto', width: 125 } );
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: i do have it inside $(document).ready... do i still need to do this?

Comment: @TroyCosentino Document ready might fire before all the images have completed loading.  When working with images you often need both `ready()` - to make sure the elements in the DOM - and `load()` on the image to handle the image itself loading.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you for the clarification. I will try this when i get back to my computer.. and you think that this makes sense for a difference on different browsers?

Comment: @TroyCosentino - it might also work to use the document (or window) load event to wrap the entire block, removing the need for applying the load handler directly to the images.  Note this will delay everything inside the handler until the page is fully loaded.  See the discussion at http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and http://api.jquery.com/load-event/.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this without javascript.
Use this in the css :

```css
#ad img {
    width: 125px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: but, for example if the image is a square i do not want it to be 125px in height, just 40x40... if that makes sense

Comment: I'm changing only the width, not touching the height.

Comment: ill try it, i dont want it to change the shape of the image though

Comment: max width will work for now, but basically i want it to be bound by either 40 height and max width, or 125 width with max height. max being the amount to keep the image natural ratio

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#ad img').each(function(){
        if($(this).width() > 125){
            $(this).height('auto');
            $(this).width(125);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
        $('#ad img').each(function(){
        if($(this).width() > 125) {
            $(this).css('height', 'auto');
            $(this).css('width',125);
        }
    })
```

Comment: yeah i think one just calls the other